# Neo4j: MERGE with comma in pattern throws 'Invalid syntax', unlike MATCH or CREATE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Good morning,

To achieve idempotence I use Neo4j's `MERGE` keyword to insert patterns into my database. For example, I might insert a user and his friends like this:

```
MERGE (friend:User)<-[:FRIEND]-(me:User)-[:FRIEND]->(anotherfriend:User);
```

I thought I could rewrite the same statement like this:

```
MERGE (me:User)-[:FRIEND]->(friend:User), (me)-[:FRIEND]->(anotherfriend:User);
```

But this results in this error:

```
Invalid input ',': expected whitespace, a relationship pattern, ON, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 41)
"MERGE (me:User)-[:FRIEND]->(friend:User), (me)-[:FRIEND]->(anotherfriend:User);"
```

`MATCH` and `CREATE` do support this syntax. Is there any reason why `MERGE` doesn't? Is it simply something that hasn't been implemented yet?

Note: this is not an actual query I'm using in my application but just something simple to illustrate my point.

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 2):

I consider this being a imperfection of the cypher implementation. Please file a github issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues for this.